# PHP Sleep Function (Email Throttling) Freezes Entire Server

Tags: php, email, sleep

I am on a standard shared Hostgator which has a limit of 500 mails per hour.

I am trying to throttle my email script to only send 1 email per 8 seconds...

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE verified='1' ORDER BY balance DESC");
while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
set_time_limit(30);
$mail->AddAddress($arr[0]);
$mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();
echo "Sent to ".$arr[0]."<br><br>";
sleep(8);
}
```

I am using PHPMailer. The script itself works fine, it emails once every 8 seconds...

But the rest of the domain freezes up completely.

Is there an alternative method of sleeping I can use that won't freeze up my whole domain?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cronjobs cannot be executed secondly, only minutely. `*/1` in the minute field will run the script every 1 minute, but you cannot get any more granular than that.

There is nothing wrong with the sleep, but do not run the command from your browser. The reason you are locking up the domain is because your Apache thread is held up on the script with sleep. Until it finishes, your requests will be blocked and queued.

I would suggest that you keep your script, and just execute it with a cronjob hourly, or every few hours. How often does it really need to run? Once a day?

The below will run it every night at 5 after midnight, and throw it to the background.

```
5 0 * * * user php -f /path/to/file &
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding us all that you can't run cron jobs by the second.

Comment: I only have about 580 users right now. What will happen if I run just run the cronjob once with the PHP sleep? Will it run in the background without freezing everything up?

Comment: Correct, if it starts from the CLI. Running it in a cronjob removed the PHP thread from Apache. This means it will run in the background on the server, leaving apache to be accessible for all users.

Comment: Awesome. I will try it then :)

Comment: May I ask what the & at the end of the crnjob does?

Comment: It puts it into the background and returns the prompt. This means it doesnt block your tty. Read this for more info: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/unix/reference/commands.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a cron job (Unix) or scheduled task (Windows) to call this script at set duration.

Or use something like [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/) to handle the sending of bulk emails.

Comment: So make a cronjob on an interval of 8 seconds..? Or just have a cronjob run the thing with the sleep command..?

Comment: Run the cron every 8 seconds.

Comment: Okay, I have an admin panel though where I am entering the email subject and message (so it's going thru POST). ANy idea how to implement that?

Comment: Have that data go to a script that adds it to the database.

Comment: K. But how would I keep track of who has received what email..? (Keep in mind that I get about 30 new users every day).

Comment: Downvoted since calling this script every 8 seconds will be a disaster - it'll launch lots of instances of scripts that are looping through every row of the database

Comment: @ernie: Why is that relevant? I don't get what the "disaster" would be. Also, spryno724's actual answer never suggested to run it every 8 seconds.

Comment: @ernie - Well I would change the script accordingly so it only sent one email for each cronjob.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - The disaster is that each instance of the script sits around 30 minutes, and will email from the same query - meaning each time it runs, it'll email the same people, and sit around.  The answer doesn't address the issue of the PHP loop itself locking the server-up - running it a cron just means it'll lock the server up at scheduled intervals.

Comment: @ernie: Oh I see what you mean - just wondering because it didn't pop out at me immediately. The thought of running *any* script every 8 seconds sounds crazy to me in the first place.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - yeah, I was responding more to the upvoting of Cole's "Run the cron every 8 seconds" comment; forgetting that cron intervals are only minutes.  Not sure if sixeightzero's answer is right in that running the script outside Apache will be less intensive, but sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be implemented directly into the script unless it is constantly running and rereads the database after every request.

I would recommend a cron job that is run every 8 seconds then reads the first entry from the database and if it exists, send the email:

1. Set up cron job to call script every 8 seconds
2. Script queries database for first entry in table
3. If data exists, send email based on that data
4. Delete the row
5. Script ends

Comment: ...or run the cron job once an hour and send 500. Makes more sense to me than every 8 seconds, batch it into chunks.

Comment: But what if it is an email verification system. I would prefer to get my email within a few minutes than an hour.

Comment: Oh yeah true, I was thinking newsletter for some reason. And as has just been posted, you can't run cron jobs by the second, would have to be once a minute at most.

Comment: You might mention to either create a new column to track sending, or using a copy of the table.  Obviously the php script will have to be rewritten to only send one email.

Answer (score 0):

You're locking up your server with the while loop. Every 8 seconds it executes 1 pass of the loop, then waits for another 8 seconds. Everything else has to wait until it's complete. Try using a cron job.