# Apache + PHP multiple scripts at the same time

Tags: php, ajax, apache, parallel-processing

Good day.

For first, sorry for my bad English =)

So. I created script:

```
<?
sleep(10);
?>
```

My Apache has MPM module, I obviously didn't use sessions in this script, just.. just sleep(10).
When I open 2 tabs in my browser simultaneously, first tab loads in 10 seconds, second tab - 20 seconds.

But. When I open this script in 2 different browsers at the same time, it loads in each one after 10 seconds.

So, I started thinking, that my problem is "Connection: Keep-Alive". I changed my script:

```
<?
  header('Connection: close');
  phpinfo();
  sleep(10);
?>
```

phpinfo() - to be sure, that headers were sent before sleep(). Buuuut... I meet the same problem. In first tab of Chrome I get headers with "Connection: close", in second tab I can't get response headers while first script is not ended. In two different browsers - everything is normal.

And now I have absolutely no ideas what I'm doing wrong. Why Chrome can't make 2 parallel queries to my site? What I should do to solve this problem?

P.S. I don't want to disable keep-alive for all my site. I don't mind, if it will speed up loading of css, images and other stuff. Even other scripts. But I want to have ability to run some scripts parallel in one browser.
P.P.S. For example: at the one page will be very long ajax query, for example - processing some big data at server-side and ajax queries with some little interval - to get status of executing first query. Obviously, that they must be parallel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101082/php-sleep-function-email-throttling-freezes-entire-server

Comment: Id guess it was your apache settings take a look at the settings for [KeepAliveTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) and [MaxKeepAliveRequests](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#maxkeepaliverequests)

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ thank you, but it's not really what I want. I know about cron, but I don't want to use it right here =) If I will not find any other solution - I'll have to use cron =(

Comment: @prodigitalson thank you. I tried to set KeepAlive Off for all my site. And with WebKit Inspector I see, that Chrome really get "Connection: close" header, but the problem is not solved - Chrome didn't make NEW connection to site, while he didn't loaded page with "Connection: close" header. May be, there is way in ajax mechanism, to say that this ajax query should be in a new connection?

Comment: I think it would be interesting if you added some logging instructions in there.

Comment: Old question but I also replicate this in Chrome and Apache 2.2.22.  Even with KeepAlive Off the second tab on chrome will not complete until the first tab is done.  I notice this when I do a somewhat long process then try to open page on the same site. Similar issue but doesn't work for me even with unique requests.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question but I just had the same problem and solved it with [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.session-write-close.php)!
Without it PHP purposely queues scripts for same session.

**Simplest possible example:**

**Looong Script #1:**

```
<?php

$_SESSION['progress'] = 0;

for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['progress']++;
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);// This is slowing script purposely!
}

?>
```

**Short script #2:**

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['progress']);
?>
```

Now try it, open first script that takes ages open second script in new tab and get the progress updated in a blink while first still running!! So easy right?! ;)

Same principle for ajax polling long script and second ajax call to get the progress!