# Chrome stalls request for 15 seconds

Tags: angular, google-chrome, connection, tcp

We have a angular 2 app that randomly stalls the request for 15 seconds. The problem seems to be that chromes runs out of TCP/IP connections. The problem is only in chrome. The request dosent get a connection id in chrome dev tab:
[Shows stalling and no connection id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqydp.jpg)

After 15 seconds the response is loaded empty.

In chrome://net-internals/#events the request looks like:

Look for the 15 second gap, what is chrome telling me?

```
t=543333 [st=   50]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=15062]
t=558395 [st=15112]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
```

All:

```
t=543283 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=15113]
                 --> priority = "MEDIUM"
                 --> url = "https://www.struqtur.se/hyperion/GraphQl?hyperionRevertParapaar=6.4186284125575295"
t=543283 [st=    0]   +URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
t=543283 [st=    0]      DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=1]
                     --> delegate_blocked_by = "tillägget Adblock Plus"
t=543284 [st=    1]   -URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE
t=543284 [st=    1]   +URL_REQUEST_START_JOB  [dt=15111]
                   --> load_flags = 258 (BYPASS_CACHE | VERIFY_EV_CERT)
                   --> method = "POST"
                   --> upload_id = "0"
                   --> url = "https://www.struqtur.se/hyperion/GraphQl?hyperionRevertParapaar=6.4186284125575295"
t=543284 [st=    1]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=543284 [st=    1]      HTTP_CACHE_GET_BACKEND  [dt=0]
t=543284 [st=    1]     +HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST  [dt=49]
t=543284 [st=    1]        HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER_BOUND
                       --> source_dependency = 45248 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB_CONTROLLER)
t=543333 [st=   50]        HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST_BOUND_TO_JOB
                       --> source_dependency = 45249 (HTTP_STREAM_JOB)
t=543333 [st=   50]     -HTTP_STREAM_REQUEST
t=543333 [st=   50]     +UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
t=543333 [st=   50]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT  [dt=0]
                       --> is_chunked = false
                       --> net_error = 0 (?)
                       --> total_size = 151
t=543333 [st=   50]     -UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_INIT
                     --> is_chunked = false
                     --> net_error = 0 (?)
                     --> total_size = 151
t=543333 [st=   50]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST  [dt=0]
t=543333 [st=   50]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS
                       --> POST /hyperion/GraphQl?hyperionRevertParapaar=6.4186284125575295 HTTP/1.1
                           Host: www.struqtur.se
                           Connection: keep-alive
                           Content-Length: 151
                           Pragma: no-cache
                           Cache-Control: no-cache
                           Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
                           Origin: https://www.struqtur.se
                           User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
                           Content-Type: application/json
                           Referer: https://www.struqtur.se/v2/day/handle
                           Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
                           Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
                           Cookie: [408 bytes were stripped]
t=543333 [st=   50]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST_BODY
                       --> did_merge = false
                       --> is_chunked = false
                       --> length = 151
t=543333 [st=   50]       +UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                       --> current_position = 0
t=543333 [st=   50]          UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                         --> current_position = 0
t=543333 [st=   50]       -UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ
t=543333 [st=   50]        UPLOAD_DATA_STREAM_READ  [dt=0]
                       --> current_position = 151
t=543333 [st=   50]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_SEND_REQUEST
t=543333 [st=   50]     +HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS  [dt=15062]
t=543333 [st=   50]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=15062]
t=558395 [st=15112]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS
                       --> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                           Date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 09:01:54 GMT
                           Server: Apache
                           Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
                           Cache-Control: no-cache, no-transform
                           Pragma: no-cache
                           Content-Length: 53
                           Connection: close
                           Content-Type: application/json
t=558395 [st=15112]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=558395 [st=15112]      URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=558395 [st=15112]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
t=558395 [st=15112]    URL_REQUEST_DELEGATE  [dt=0]
t=558395 [st=15112]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=0]
t=558395 [st=15112]    URL_REQUEST_JOB_FILTERED_BYTES_READ
                   --> byte_count = 53
t=558395 [st=15112]    HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_BODY  [dt=1]
t=558396 [st=15113] -REQUEST_ALIVE
```

[Fininshed request in chrome dev tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkF7l.jpg)

I have read in many threads and tried to solve the problem without luck

[Chrome stalls when making multiple requests to same resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46104

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447463

The threads/problems that i found is similar but there solutions is not working så i hope someone has experience of this type of problem and have any idea

Comment: What code causes this issue? How many requests are you trying to make concurrently? Why do you think this is related to Angular?

Comment: The code is a simple Angular Post/GET request, we use apollo client as well but the initiator dosent seems to be the problem

About 7 request at once
https://s2.postimg.org/mvzs9eqp5/Sk_rmklipp.jpg

Its maybe more reletad to chrome but in this case its angular that "initiates" the problem

Comment: Can you reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: The app is to big to upload to stackblitz. The problem is also only releted to some clients not all, for the most clients it works.

Comment: I doubt there is much others can do.

Comment: But can you understand the rows:

    t=543333 [st=   50]        HTTP_STREAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS  [dt=15062]
    t=558395 [st=15112]        HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS

What hapens here? what is chrome telling me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with Chrome, but my app doesn't use Angular. But the `net-internals/#events` entries for stalled requests are identical, when they happen, and usually the affected requests similarly stall for up to 15 seconds, but usually more like 5-10 seconds.

In my case, it happens when the app hits an internal API, and the server-side logs are totally normal for stalled requests (i.e. the API call doesn't take longer than usual), so I know it's something in Chrome. The client apps are deployed on Chromeboxes, which might be significant because I can't reproduce the problem on my workstation.

@torpare-nilsson did you manage to find anything more about this? I saw you opened an issue on Angular's GitHub but got bounced back to SO, which may have been warranted since this looks to be a Chrome issue.

Comment: We have not sort this out. But its a client-side issue and reletead to chrome, that is what we know. 

Width keepalive on server we managed to reuse the connections (connectionId (TCP/IP)) and the freqvens of the problem decreased but not solved it, more a workaround. 

In our case it happens only on our own computers, not our costumers (4000). The diffrent are that we can swich between costumers accounts and its seems to that is causing the problem. But  that is just an observation more than a cause of the problem. After restart of the computer  the problem is still there.