# Understanding simple tornado.gen.coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to understand how tornado works. While understanding, I tried to implement a simple coroutine example using `tornado.gen`. But the example doesn't seem to work. Any leads on what is going wrong here?

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        print("Handling starts")
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(5)
        print("Handling ends")
        self.write('Hi')
```

When I open multiple browser tabs and try to request the server, all the requests except the current one gets blocked and tornado seems to handle these requests in a synchronous way:

```
Handling starts
Handling ends
Handling starts
Handling ends
Handling starts
Handling ends
Handling starts
Handling ends
Handling starts
Handling ends
Handling starts
Handling ends
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers don't make multiple requests to the same resource at the same time. For more explanation, see: [Chrome stalls when making multiple requests to same resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource)

This has also been mentioned in Tornado [FAQs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html#my-code-is-asynchronous-but-it-s-not-running-in-parallel-in-two-browser-tabs).

Anyway, to see the *asynchronous* behaviour of Tornado, make one request from your browser, and another from your terminal:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/
```

You should see the the output as expected.