# How avoid Chrome's stalling when accessing REST endpoints

Tags: rest, api, google-chrome, polling

I have a server which has multiple REST endpoints which I want to query in parallel with `Javascript`. I try to query e.g. 10 endpoints at the same time. However, chrome only allows to execute 6 queries at the same time which is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing-explanation). So my waterfall diagram looks like the following:
[image]
6 requests are executed in parallel while the rest is stalled. I want to disable the stalling. How can I do that? I am using the latest Version of Chrome (  75.0.3770.100) and I tried multiple values for the Cache-Control Header field which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource) - non of them worked:

```
max-age=3, must-revalidate
```

[image]

```
no-cache, no-transform
```

[image]

```
no-store
```

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Here is my test code with which I generate the requests:

```
<html>
 <head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
let i=0;
while(i<20){
  $.ajax({url: "http://127.0.0.1:9998/abc", headers:{
    'Cache-Control':'no-store'
  }, success: function(result){
    console.log("done");
  }});
i++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options are:

- **Use HTTP/2.0**. With HTTP/2.0 just a single connection is used, but the requests and responses are multiplexed. The result is that all request can be sent at once, the server executions several ones in parallel and starts further ones before the previous responses have reached the client.
- **Use several hostnames**: The limit of 6 concurrent connections is per host. If you use several hostnames, you can execute more than 6 concurrent requests.

Comment: I can not change the hostname and also not the protocol so far - I am looking for a solution based on http1