# Javascript fetch in parallel only after disable cache in devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, devtools

The fetch request in javascript:

```
async () => {
     try {
       const urls = [
         "http://localhost:3001/foo",
         "http://localhost:3001/foo",
         "http://localhost:3001/foo",
         "http://localhost:3001/foo",
       ];
   
       const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url));
       const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
       const errors = responses.filter((response) => !response.ok);
       }
}
```

I want the request to fire in parallel. But in dev tools in chrome this is shown:

[image]

Now when i disable the cache in devtools, it does work in parallel:

[image]

[image]

Confused on how to make it work without disabling the cache in devtools.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the first one is just so fast? With the cache disabled there might also be small differences in when the requests kick off but because the whole thing takes longer the difference isn't noticable? Would be curious to see the absolute numbers. (how long do they take?)

Comment: The server is setup to take 2 sec per request and accepts requests in parallel. In the mean time i found a SO post describing the same problem. Requesting to the same enndpoint 4 times was just to test things out, so this should not be a problem i hope. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found the answer in this post:

[Chrome stalls when making multiple requests to same resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource)

Apparently browsers try to cache requests to the same endpoint.