# Continuous polling to backend is stalling (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, express, axios

I have a Vue component that conditionally renders other components depending on the GET response. When boiled down it looks something like:

```
data() {
   return {
      responseStatus: null, // Variable that conditionally renders components
      response: null,
      poll: null
   }
},

created() {
   this.lookup()

   this.poll = setInterval(() => {
      this.lookup()
   }, 15000)
},

methods: {
   lookup() {
      axios.get(`...`)
         .then((res) => {
            this.response = res.data
            console.log(this.response, 'response')
            
            if (this.response.active) {
               this.responseStatus = 0
            } else {
               this.responseStatus = 1
               clearInterval(this.poll)
            }
         })
         .catch((e) => {
            clearInterval(this.poll)
            console.log(e)
            this.responseStatus = 2
         })
   },
}
```

`this.lookup()` fires an initial get request which tells the backend to look something up and, if that something doesn't exist, to write it to the database and return a database aggregation. this can take upwards of ~10 minutes due to rate limits.

Because the first `this.lookup()` can take time, I want to allow users to see the progress of their request via polling - every 15 seconds fire the same method using `setInterval()`. The backend is designed such that if the original request is being written to the database, it will return an object that looks like:

```
{
   active: true,
   current: 38,
   queue: 748
}
```

**The problem** is that each request fired via `setInterval()` pends for ~20 seconds and I'm not sure why because typical responses to the server take ~500ms from start-to-finish. I would like to remove this 20 second stall.

[image: Network waterfall]
[image: Highlighting one of the setInterval requests]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it wasn't a conflict with any of my code but an issue with Chrome.

ref: [Chrome stalls when making multiple requests to same resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource?answertab=trending#tab-top)

fix: adding arbitrary params to the query string resolves the stalling issue.

```
// Increment this.unique on each setInterval() call (0, 1, 2, 3...)

axios.get(url, {
  params: {
    rand: this.unique
  }
})
.then(...)
```